# SevenZipSharp library: Cannot encrypt headers

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, sevenzipsharp

My task is to create the password protected ZIP with the SevenZipSharp library.

I managed to make the files contents locked with the password, however the archive structure - file names, directories hierarchy can be viewed in any of the WinZip, 7-Zip or Compressed folder.

I use the `cmp.EncryptHeaders = true;` however it seems to have no effect...

How can I encrypt the files and directories names? Thanks.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string LibraryPath = @"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.dll";
        SevenZipCompressor.SetLibraryPath(LibraryPath);

        var cmp = new SevenZipCompressor();
        cmp.CompressionMethod = CompressionMethod.Default;
        cmp.CompressionLevel = CompressionLevel.Fast;
        cmp.ArchiveFormat = OutArchiveFormat.Zip;  // compatible with WinZip and Compressed folder
        cmp.ZipEncryptionMethod = ZipEncryptionMethod.ZipCrypto;  // compatible with old WinZip
        cmp.EncryptHeaders = true;

        cmp.FileCompressionStarted += (sender, e) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(((FileNameEventArgs)e).FileName);
        };

        const string archive = @"C:\temp\12.3G.zip";
        File.Delete(archive);
        cmp.CompressDirectory(@"C:\temp\Photos", archive, "password");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the source code, it appears the only way for that flag to take effect is to use `SevenZip` for the `OutArchiveFormat`.

From the source code:

```
if (EncryptHeaders && _archiveFormat == OutArchiveFormat.SevenZip && !SwitchIsInCustomParameters("he"))
{
    names.Add(Marshal.StringToBSTR("he"));
    var tmp = new PropVariant {VarType = VarEnum.VT_BSTR, Value = Marshal.StringToBSTR("on")};
    values.Add(tmp);
}
```

Comment: It's not a solution in your case, since you want to have your format as Zip and EncryptHeaders only works with SevenZip archives.